# How much land to keep a sauropod in captivity?

Tags: agriculture, dinosaurs

How large of an area in acres would a large sauropod (Apatosaurus) need to maintain itself while also not eating all of the vegetation within the area.

So basically how large of a forested area would I need that could support a sauropod indefinitely, without needing extra foliage put into the area?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things: tree count, type, age just from start. And we know not that much about sauropod.

Comment: How big your apatosaurus is as their mass range is huge.

Comment: Couple of square meters in the freezing cold of Antartica. Put the lizard under ice, and it won't consume anything.

Comment: Related:  [Where to Keep Your Dinosaur?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/103036/where-to-keep-your-dinosaur)

Answer (score 7):

## It depends

#### How much edible biomass does a forest generate?

This highly depends on what portion of the foliage is edible to a dinosaur. Since we don't really know how efficient a dinosaur's metabolism is, and we don't know how good they were at eating things like sticks, it is hard to say. But we can do some estimates.

First, [Kloeppel, et al., 2007](https://www.srs.fs.usda.gov/pubs/ja/ja_kloeppel002.pdf) as some estimates of net primary productivity for forest-dominated ecosystems. Here are some minimum and maximum calculated values from Table 1 of that paper:

```
                   Annual Net Primary Productivity (g/m^2)
Forest Type               Minimum        Maximum
Boreal evergreen             120            439
Boreal deciduous             169            635
Temperate evergreen           60           1555
Temperate deciduous          230            555
Tropical evergreen           140           1505
```

So there is wide variety in the mount of green biomass generated by such forests. The percentage of what a forest generates that a sauropod could eat is also variable. In an evergreen forest of juniper and pinyon pine, in the foothills of the Rockies, 100% of the biomass would be within the distance that a Sauropod could reach. But in an old growth Virginia hardwood forest, the trees would all be 100 feet+ and maybe only 10% of the biomass would be accessible to a sauropod. Also consider that a sauropod isn't the only creature eating in a forest. Bugs will get theirs, squirrels or other similar creature will eat acorns and seeds, etc.

Let us use a range of assumptions then. The worst case scenario would be something like 10 g/m$^2$ of edible biomass, the best case something like 200 g/m$^2$.

#### How much does a sauropod need to eat?

The problem with a bulk biomass calculation is that there is no accounting for nutrition. You need to eat a lot less mass in leaves if you can get good nutrition from acorns.

But, ignoring that problem, let us assume that a sauropod scales up linearly from an elephant. An elephant in the wild eats something like 250 kg of biomass each day. Now, lets assume a sauropod is 8 times as massive as an elephant (so elephants average about 3 tons, and apatosaurus about 24 tons). Then an apatosaurus needs to eat 2000 kg of biomass each day.

#### Conclusion

For our worst case forest, that is 20 hectares; for the best case, 1 hectare. That is the total per dinosaur, so a group of dinosaurs would have to multiply by group size....a 'family' of 10 sauropods would need 10-200 hectares. Then we also have to multiply by some 'bad conditions' factor. If food supply is lower in a bad year, a dry summer, or what have you, then you would have to account for that in the area needed.

Overall, I think it is reasonable to expect something in the range of 5-100 hectares per single sauropod, depending on the fertility of the local soil, whether or not the local biomass is accessible to the dinosaurs, etc.

Comment: James Farlow (1987) calculates that an Apatosaurus-sized dinosaur about 35 t (34 long tons; 39 short tons) would have possessed 5.7 t (5.6 long tons; 6.3 short tons) of fermentation contents.[66] Assuming Apatosaurus had an avian respiratory system and a reptilian resting-metabolism, Frank Paladino et al. (1997) estimate the animal would have needed to consume only about 262 liters (58 imp gal; 69 U.S. gal) of water per day.[63] (wiki)

Comment: yields ~5000 kg in the gut, assuming a 3-day digestion period, yields ~1700 kg/day

Comment: @theRiley First, you should link your references, at least to a citation; took me like 15 minutes to determine what papers you were referring to. Second, I found the Farlow reference but the Paladino reference is in a book, I can't look it up in my university journal account, and don't see it available online anywere. So I can't comment on what it says. But how do you go from 5.7 t in the gut to 5 kg in the gut? You must mean the estimate is 1.7t = 3400 kg per day. In that case, not too different from what I estimated.

Comment: was just trying to help with a slight bit of different rigor directly related to the genus. 5.6 long tons fermentation contents => ~5000 kg in the gut. (I) assume a three day fill/digest process => ~1700 kg/day intake, for a 34 long ton beast. i did not drill down to the underlying reference. you are welcome for the upvote